# How to replace only alphabet characters in my string using regex?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am having trouble with replacing the alphabet characters in a string that contains special characters.

```py
import re

s = 'F6[ab]\nF3[ab]'
n = 'F6[ab]' # <= want to keep this in my string but want to change 'ab' in the new line
k = 'ab' # <= do not want to keep this in my string
c = '1' # <= change 'ab' -> '1'
re.sub(f'(?!{n}){k}', c, s)
# => 'F6[ab]\nF3[1'
# but I want this output
# => 'F6[ab]\nF3[1]'
```

Comment: Running this code gives `F6[1]\nF3[1]`, is your given output incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use grouping in your regex to capture and preserve what you want to keep in final result. Use it in a lambda `re.sub` like this:

```py
import re

s = 'F6[ab]\nF3[ab]'
n = 'F6[ab]' # <= want to keep this in my string but want to change 'ab' in the new line
k = 'ab' # <= do not want to keep this in my string
c = '1' # <= change 'ab' -> '1'

repl = re.sub(r'(' + re.escape(n) + rf')|\b{k}\b',
   lambda m: m.group(1) if m.group(1) else c, s)
```

**Output:**

```
'F6[ab]\nF3[1]'
```

It makes following regex:

```
(F6\[ab\])|\bab\b
```

[<kbd>Code Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/dD8pcU)

Comment: How would you change the pattern if you wanted to exclude two words?

Comment: Usually it is done using negative lookahead like `(?!word1|word2)` before matching right most alternation

Comment: It's not working.

Comment: not working because requirements are not part of the questions asked. It is not proper to add new requirements later. I suggest you post a new question so that we can understand it better and answer.